# What could cause Launcher.LaunchFileAsync to fail intermittently

Tags: windows-store-apps, storagefile

In my windows store app, I allow users to open up a file, it does not exist locally then app will download it and save it the local folder of the app and then try to open it using the code below.
**This works intermittently, other time the call returns false**.

```cs
var launcherOption = new LauncherOptions();
launcherOption.DesiredRemainingView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ViewSizePreference.Default;
launcherOption.DisplayApplicationPicker = userSettings.ShowApplicationPicker;

bool success;
// fileResponse.File is a StorageFile object
if (fileResponse.OpenAs == ContentOpenOption.LocalFile)
    success = await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(fileResponse.File, launcherOption);
else
    success = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(fileResponse.WebUri, launcherOption);
```

Things I have checked for:

- The file is not restricted by windows ( eg: I am testing with txt, jpg files, not exe, bin, bat )
- My app is visible at the time this call is made
- The call is made on the UI Thread by using the code below:

```cs
var launcherOption = new LauncherOptions();
                    launcherOption.DesiredRemainingView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ViewSizePreference.UseHalf;
                    launcherOption.DisplayApplicationPicker = userSettings.ShowApplicationPicker;

                    var dispatcherObject = CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;
                    if (dispatcherObject != null && dispatcherObject.HasThreadAccess == false)
                    {
                        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
                                Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                async () =>
                                {
                                    if (fileResponse.OpenAs == ContentOpenOption.LocalFile)
                                        success = await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(fileResponse.File, launcherOption);
                                    else
                                    {
                                        launcherOption.TreatAsUntrusted = true;
                                        success = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(fileResponse.WebUri, launcherOption);
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (fileResponse.OpenAs == ContentOpenOption.LocalFile)
                            success = await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(fileResponse.File, launcherOption);
                        else
                        {
                            launcherOption.TreatAsUntrusted = true;
                            success = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(fileResponse.WebUri, launcherOption);
                        }
                    }

                    if (!success)
                    {
                        content.IsContentUpdating = false;
                        content.ContentStatus = string.Empty;
                        logger.LogMessage(string.Format("Unable to open file. {0}",   
                        content.Name), LoggingLevel.Error);
                   }
   }
```

- Made sure that the file is not blocked by windows by checking it's properties.

**Any other ideas what I might be missing here?**

Comment: You didn't list your download code, but make sure the file has actually finished downloading. This can cause an intermittent failure depending on file size, timing etc.

Comment: I am using BackGroundDownloader and awaiting for it to finish. Even if it failed due to that then i should now be able to open it next time as the file is now cached locally. I can open it if i go to that directory and click on it.

Comment: If your code is running on the ui thread, why are you using `Dispatcher.RunAsync`? I thought `Dispatcher.RunAsync` was generally only used from a worker thread to run things on the ui thread.

Comment: It's one of the things i tried, just to make sure that i am not hitting that corner case, the original code( posted above) doesn't use it.

Comment: My guess would be either 1) your original code might not run on the UI thread. or 2) your dispatcher was null and you caught the null ref exception, so your never called your Launcher code.

Comment: So i have updated the code above that works for all file that will not be blocked by windows, but it now return falsw for every file, even though the file is launched successfully :(